# Printer Android - The printer prints dot at the beginning of the line

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to print on a bluetooth dpp 350 printer with react native.
The printer is printing correctly. However, a point is leaving at the beginning of each line.

I already tried several encoding and also codepage and I could not remove that point at the beginning of the line.

I'm using the react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer library

```
let config = {
     encoding: 'ISO8859_1',
     codepage: 1,
     widthtimes: 0,
     heigthtimes: 0,
     fonttype: 1
}

await  BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText("Testando impressão!\r\n", config);     
await  BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText("I need help!\r\n", config);     
await  BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText("I need help!\r\n", config);     
await  BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText("I need help!\r\n", config);     
await  BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText("I need help!\r\n", config);
```

[image]

Please, does anyone know how to remove this point from the beginning of the line?

Comment: This is a line printer, it may do that as part of its firmware.  Its probably not part of your app that's causing it.  The one thing worth trying is to send the entire thing as one printText and see if that removes it from lines 2-n.

Comment: Eae Renato, blz? Você conseguiu imprimir image com essa lib?

Comment: @MaxFerreira consegui imprimir, sim! Embora o projeto não tinha impressão de imagens eu fiz alguns testes e imprimiu. Devolvi a impressora para o cliente. Já finalizei o projeto do cliente.

Comment: Did you manage to remove the dots? Facing the same issue with a Zebra iMZ320

Comment: @PabloQuemé do not. I had to change the printer.

Comment: @RenatoSouzadeOliveira same here, tried with a different printer and no dots appeared.